# Is it possible to see the real time number of users and stuff?

Tags: support

Is there any way to see kind of basic data of this site, for example, the real time number of users, the time zone distribution of the number, the weekly distribution? If I can do that, I might be able to post my questions effectively. I’d like to consider a strategy for posting.

Of course, the most important things to attract people to my questions might be to post good questions, to write logically and simply, to improve my writing English, but I would think it would be better to do everything I can to get better answers.

I was hoping I could see such data somewhere in this site.

P.S.: It’s been about three months since I joined EL&U. I really enjoy this site. I’d like to say thank you, and I love you from the bottom of my heart!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of queries that you can run at Data.SE. You can get site-wide queries, as well as personally user-specific ones. All you'll need to know, for the user-specific ones, are your user ID number. You can grab this by going to your profile, and noting the number in the search box.

Comment: Those data are not in real time, though.

Comment: @kiamaluno No, but even "old" data can give trends that would be useful for someone who is trying to maximize the visibility of his question.

Comment: @simchona Thanks for the info. Er…but it might be beyond me to use that to maximize the visibility of my question. It seems to require the skill of analysts to use the data. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Besides running queries as mentioned in simchona's answer (which entails entering SQL queries, as described in the [data.stackexchange.com/faq](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq)), you can download "data dumps" for some stackexchange sites, as described in a  [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/).  Once you download that data, you can analyze it however you like.  As an example, see [stackapps question #2344](https://stackapps.com/questions/2344/ask-ubuntu-data-server-blazing-fast-searches-from-the-data-dump-and-api).

Also, a site called [hewgill.com/~greg](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/) has a [webpage](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/english_language_and_usage/stats.html) called *English Language and Usage Statistics* that shows average number of questions by day of week and by hour of day, etc., together with portions of the queries used to generate the datasets. [image: questions by hour of day]
At the moment, those charts appear to be up to date (that is, incorporate March 2012 quarterly data) but elsewhere on the site, data in [per-user statistics](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/english_language_and_usage/users/) appears to be a few months older.

Comment: Thanks for the good info.